# C++ unresolved external symbol with 50% chance on 2 virtual abstract methods

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract, unresolved-external

Visual Studio 2015, 2 classes and real ambiguity.
Class ICommandLine has next relevant code:

```
 class ICommandLine 
   {
   public:
      virtual void CL_AssignCommandExecMaps() abstract;
      virtual void CL_RecieveCommand(string) abstract;
   };
```

And class World derived from ICommandLine has next relevant code:

```
class World : public ICommandLine
   {
   public:
      virtual void CL_RecieveCommand(string commandLine) override;
      virtual void CL_AssignCommandExecMaps() override;
   };
```

So the problem, error list:

```
1>World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ICommandLine::CL_AssignCommandExecMaps(void)" (?CL_AssignCommandExecMaps@ICommandLine@@UEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ICommandLine::ICommandLine(void)" (??0ICommandLine@@QEAA@XZ)
```

What means that CL_RecieveCommand overriden just fine, but CL_AssignCommandExecMaps is still unresolved.
This problem easily can be solved by putting {} instead of abstract keyword, but I really need this class to be abstract.
Why am I getting this error even if definitions for both methods does exists?

Comment: `abstract` is not a C++ keyword. It may or may not be a Microsoft extension. You may want to define pure virtual methods like this `virtual void CL_AssignCommandExecMaps() = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe hackneyed subject, but anyways...
I just looked into ICommandLine constructor:

```
ICommandLine() 
{
    registered.push_back(this);
    CL_AssignCommandExecMaps(); // <- This is call of undefined method
}
```